# Como generar 1 JSON apartir de 2 consultas a base de datos mediante linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy generando 2 consultas mediante 1 argumento, la primera es un procedimiento almacenado que me esta respondiendo de la siguiente manera:

**CONSULTA**

```
var resultadoSP = (from bt in bd.ListadoGeneradoOrdenes.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE BuscarDatos " + @clave) select new ListadoGeneradoOrdenes {
  Clave = bt.Clave,
    Cliente = bt.Cliente,
    Num_ClienteL = bt.Num_ClienteL,
    FechaRealizo = bt.FechaRealizo,
    Num_Trabajador = bt.Num_Trabajador,
    Nom_Trabajador = bt.Nom_Trabajador,
    TipoUnidad = bt.TipoUnidad,
    Operador = bt.Operador,
    Responsable = bt.Responsable,
    Direccion = bt.Direccion,
    Correo = bt.Correo
}).ToList();
```

En su respuesta viene siendo la siguiente:

```
[{
  "clave": "000001014147002000439710",
  "cliente": "cliente 1",
  "num_ClienteL": "0000100108",
  "fechaRealizo": "2022-07-21T09:50:50.483",
  "num_Trabajador": "1111",
  "nom_Trabajador": "trabajador 1",
  "tipoUnidad": "PLATAFORMA",
  "operador": "OPERADOR DE PRUEBA",
  "responsable": "RESPONSABLE",
  "direccion": "ACTUALIZAR",
  "correo": "ACTUALIZAR"
}]
```

con respecto a la siguiente consulta es así:

```
var resultadoBD = (from b in bd.OrdenesPt where b.CveCompuesta.Equals(clave) select new {
  Ot = b.Ot,
    Numero_Cliente = b.Numero_Cliente,
    Pedido = b.Pedido,
    Posicion = b.Posicion,
    Sociedad = b.Sociedad,
    CodigoMaterial = b.CodigoMaterial,
    Material = b.Material,
    Cantidad = b.Cantidad
}).ToList();
```

con su respuesta así:

```
[{
    "ot": "1",
    "numero_Cliente": "0000100108",
    "pedido": "0020004397",
    "posicion": 10,
    "sociedad": "1",
    "codigoMaterial": "1",
    "material": "1",
    "cantidad": 1
  },
  {
    "ot": "2",
    "numero_Cliente": "0000100108",
    "pedido": "0020004397",
    "posicion": 30,
    "sociedad": "1",
    "codigoMaterial": "1",
    "material": "1",
    "cantidad": 1
  }
  //Hasta n posiciones
]
```

A lo cual con respecto de unirlo me refiero a que me entregue una respuesta así:

```
[{
  "clave": "000001014147002000439710",
  "cliente": "cliente 1",
  "num_ClienteL": "0000100108",
  "fechaRealizo": "2022-07-21T09:50:50.483",
  "num_Trabajador": "1111",
  "nom_Trabajador": "trabajador 1",
  "tipoUnidad": "PLATAFORMA",
  "operador": "OPERADOR DE PRUEBA",
  "responsable": "RESPONSABLE",
  "direccion": "ACTUALIZAR",
  "correo": "ACTUALIZAR"
  "Partidas": [{
      "ot": "1",
      "numero_Cliente": "0000100108",
      "pedido": "0020004397",
      //Demas propiedades
    },
    {
      //N registros
    }
    //Hasta n posiciones
  ]
}]
```

En algunos foros que consulte hacían mención de hacer uso de  `Intersect` a lo cual probé con `var union = resultadoSP.Intersect(resultadoBD);`, lo cual me genera un error ya que no se puede realizar la intersección, porque tiene diferente estructura en su clase, de ahí intente convertirlo en formato JSON, con esta [guía](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1) de microsoft especificamente en donde hace mención en *Serialization example* , pero aun asi no he logrado convertir la respuesta.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Encontré una manera de realizar lo, hice lo siguiente:

```
var ls = resultadoSP.Zip(resultadoBD, (a, b) =>
  new {
    Clave = a.Clave,
      Cliente = a.Cliente,
      //Varias Propiedades ...
      ListadoPartidas = new List < OrdenesPt > {

        new OrdenesPt {
          Ot = b.Ot,
            Numero_Cliente = b.Numero_Cliente,
            Pedido = b.Pedido,
            Posicion = b.Posicion,
            //Más propiedades ...
        }
      }
  }).ToList();
```

Me imprime tal cual como quiero, pero ahora el inconveniente es que no puedo iterar la cantidad de registros almacenados en **`resultadoBD`** (un ejemplo 3), **solo accede al primer registro**

Comment: ¿Sí sabes que para responder a las preguntas, se utiliza la parte inferior? Bueno, ahora lo sabes, recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta haciendo click en el check del costado. Saludos y que sigan los éxitos :D

Comment: Listo ya publique la respuesta
!

Comment: Excelente, al costado de la respuesta hay un check que solo puede ser marcado por la persona que realizó la pregunta. Me parece que hay una restricción de 24 horas para ello, es importante marcar respuestas como aceptadas, esto aumenta la buena salud del sitio por efecto del % de preguntas resueltas. Gracias por tu cooperación :D

Comment: Si, lastimosamente es hasta las 24 hrs :(, pero lo haré

Comment: Normal, masbien, gracias por la buena onda con el sitio y las reglas. :D

Comment: No hay problema, igual he estado consultado datos de otras respuestas publicadas que me han ayudado bastante!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución**

En donde describí que solo accedía al primer registro, lo que hice fue solo apuntar a la primer consulta y quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
var ls = resultadoSP.Zip(resultadoBD, (a, b) =>
      new {
        Clave = a.Clave,
          Cliente = a.Cliente,
          //Varias Propiedades ...
          ListadoPartidas = resultadoBD
      }).ToList();
```

La clave importante es que a travez de utilizar Zip, pude unir las 2 respuestas y para poder llegar a la solición que me planteaba, es que leyendo en algunos foros era que formateaban la respuesta. Para ello hice eso:

```
ListadoPartidas = new List < OrdenesPt > {

        new OrdenesPt {
          Ot = b.Ot,
            Numero_Cliente = b.Numero_Cliente,
            Pedido = b.Pedido,
            Posicion = b.Posicion,
            //Más propiedades ...
        }
      }
```

Cosa que fue una solución si solo tenia un registro en la lista, cosa que es de manera aleatoria, que esta se obtiene la longitud dependiendo de la cantidad de registros encontrados de la primer respuesta, para ello siguiendo la idea, solo basto asignarle la respuesta obtenida de:

```
var resultadoBD = (from b in bd.OrdenesPt where b.CveCompuesta.Equals(clave) select new { //sus propiedades ...};
```

y llegue a la unión como necesitaba la respuesta.